# Titanium Mobile - Invert text color in TableVIew when selecting a row

Tags: colors, selection, cell, tableview, titanium

I am playing around with Titanium Mobile. I built a TableView and test it on the iPhone. All works fine, I enabled the "selection" property for the TableView.

What I can't figure out easily is how to inver the text color so that when a row is Selected an the background is blue, the text s switched from my black or gray to white, so that the contrast is just as on the iPhone.

Any ideas?

THX
Czar

Answer (score 3):

I dont know if you have UILabels in you cells, but the basic way to handle this is through the properties the API provides

[See API Documentation](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.UI.TableViewRow-object)

```
selectedBackgroundColor - the background color to render when the row cell is selected
selectedBackgroundImage - the background image to render when the row cell is selected
selectedColor           - color of the row during selection
```

Comment: I build up a custom row with several Titanium.Ui.Labels inside. According to the API, only the row itself can have "selected..." values. Any other ideas?

Comment: then it gets complicated.. you are going to have to manage updating the UI of each element individually when they get selected

Comment: Do you maybe have any code snipplet I could use as starting point?